# How to split one column of database into multiple columns and compare the values of date-time datatype with string datatype

Tags: mysql, database, excel, sql-server-2008, join

I have two different MS excel sheets containing 40000 rows of data having around 12 columns.I would like to import the data from both the sheets in a database(any database can be used) into 2 different tables(table_a & table_b). Now, there is column(with column name: "start_time") in 'table_a' with the datatype 'date/time' and the value stored is "08:30:50". Also, there is a column(with column name: "total_time") in 'table_b' with the datatype 'string' and the value stored is "0800-1000".

My question here is, by looking the value "08:30:50" I understand that it falls in the range "0800-1000". But how can do this with a sql query considering that I will be using MS SQL 2005 or MS SQL 2008?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can your total_time column have value like '0830-1030' ?

Comment: yes, that could also be a probability

Answer (score 0):

this could be the solution :-

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare @table_a Table
(
     Id         Int Identity(1,1)
    ,starttime  Datetime
)

Declare @table_b Table
(
     Id         Int Identity(1,1)
    ,total_time Varchar(100)
)

Insert Into @table_a(starttime) Values
 ('08:30:50')
,('06:30:50')

Insert Into @table_b(total_time) Values
 ('0600-0759')
,('0800-1000')

Select   a.Id
        ,a.starttime
        ,b.total_time
From    (
            Select   Id
                    ,b.total_time
                    ,Cast(Left(b.total_time,2) +':'+ Right(Left(b.total_time,4),2) As time) As StartHours
                    ,Cast(Left(Right(b.total_time,4),2) +':'+ Right(b.total_time,2) As time) As EndHours
            From    @table_b As b
        ) As b
        Join @table_a As a On Cast(a.starttime As Time) >= b.StartHours And Cast(a.starttime As Time) <= b.EndHours
```

**Output :-**

[image]

Comment: Hi Mihir, I modified the query you gave as solution and tried executing it MS Access. However, I am getting an error while executing the query. The error says 'Error is FROM Clause' and then it redirects the control on the word 'Join' in the query.

Comment: This is MS SQL Server syntax, search exact syntax for MS Access.

Comment: Hi Mihir, I tried running a query for declaring the table variable for my table in MS SQL 2008 R2. But it is giving me the following error: "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '('." The syntax of my variable declaration query is same as what you have showed earlier and only the column names have changed. Please help

Comment: I tried executing the following queries to overcome the above mentioned issues:

Comment: However, sql server gives an error that the @tablevariable1 & @ tablevariable2 must be declared when they are already declared

Comment: I sorted out the issue of incorrect syntax by using the query "CREATE TYPE" specifying appropriate column names for both the tables and then this query "Declare @tablevariable As [dbo].[tablename]" again for both the tables. Then when i try to execute the "SELECT" query given above in solution by alternating the columns names as per my tables it gives me the error saying "Must declare tablevariables" however they are already declared.

Comment: sorry for late, but now a days, due to deadline, i could not able to spend time on stack overflow. now is it working ?

Comment: Dear Mihir, Pls don't be sorry.I understand.And now there is one good news and bad news. The good part is that there are no errors. But when I execute all the queries considering 40K rows in each table, so total 80K rows in both the tables. the output rows shouldn't be more than 80K, but the query execution continues till more than 20mins and no. of rows in output are in lakhs i.e. multiple rows having repetitive data is observed. Please help me how would this be a case?

Comment: can you able to include some sample data of your both tables in your question?

Comment: Sorry Mihir, the data is bit confidential and hence i can't upload it here. Let me put the question in a simple way now: I need to check values in col1, col2 & col3 of table1 whether they are matching with values in col3, col4 & col6 "respectively" of table2 and only then for the rows where these values are matching only for those rows i need the JOIN and Cast functions to work.

Comment: I am not saying, put actual data. Give dummy data like "abc", 1, 1000-1030, which matches with table structure you are having, so, anyone can help you further.

Comment: Hi Mihir, how are you doing? With reference to above solution that you gave what can do if I want to only compare that whether value(time) from row-1 of table_a falls in the value(time range) from row-1 of table_b? like row to row mapping only.